# Store values from file to an array

Tags: c

```
int main() {
    char input[50];
    setbuf(stdout,0);
    printf("Please enter filename");
    scanf("%s",input);
    cfPtr = fopen(input, "r");

    int i;

    if (cfPtr == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error Reading File\n");
        exit (0);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 1440; i++)
    {
        fscanf(cfPtr, "%d", &okay[i] );
        fclose(cfPtr);
    }
}
```

I cant seem to get this to work, the file is of type (csv) and has the contents:

```
Time    On/off
00:00   0
00:01   0
00:02   0
00:03   0
00:04   0
00:05   0
00:06   0
00:07   0
00:08   0
00:09   0
00:10   0
00:11   0
00:12   0
00:13   0
00:14   0
00:15   0
00:16   0
00:17   0
00:18   0
00:19   0
```

which continues for 24 hours. All I want is to store these values into an array. The file is called `HeatingSchedule00.csv`. Any help would be hot.

Comment: That is not a csv(comma separated values) file

Comment: you call `fclose` in each iteration of cycle, this is completely wrong

Comment: 1. What do you want to store in your array, juste the lines in the file (eg :"00:18   0") or do you want to make a kind of dictionnary with a key "00:18" and the value "0" ?
2. you have to move your `fclose` statement outside of the `for` loop

Comment: Always check the return value of functions, especially if they are doing I/O. `fscanf()` returns a value that indicates how many variables it succesfully parsed.

Comment: Thanks for the help!!

Comment: firstly, there are supposed to be commas, that is my fault for not copying down correctly. Secondly I need to copy each line as is because there is a function that is given which can separate the two parts of this array into 2 arrays.

Answer (score 0):

In general, avoid `scanf` or `fscanf`. The trouble they get into is if they don't fully read a line you might get the filehandle stuck in the middle of a line. This is what is happening to you. `fscanf` is failing to parse the first line, since it doesn't contain numbers, and it's just doing it over and over and over again.

The generally safe way to read and parse lines from a file is to first read the whole line with `fgets`, then scan it with `sscanf`.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main() {
    char input[256];
    setbuf(stdout,0);
    printf("Please enter filename: ");

    /* ALWAYS put a limit on %s in scanf, else you risk a buffer overflow if
       there's more input than you allocated memory for. */
    scanf("%255s",input);

    FILE *cfPtr = fopen(input, "r");
    if( cfPtr == NULL ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't open %s: %s\n", input, strerror(errno));
        exit(1);
    }

    char line[1024];
    char header1[21];
    char header2[21];
    while( fgets(line, 1024, cfPtr) ) {
        int hour, min, setting;

        /* Scan for the numbers first because they're more common */
        if( sscanf(line, "%d:%d\t%d", &hour, &min, &setting) == 3 ) {
            printf("%02d:%02d is %d\n", hour, min, setting);
        }
        else if( sscanf(line, "%20s\t%20s", header1, header2) == 2 ) {
            printf("Header: %s, %s\n", header1, header2);
        }
        else {
            fprintf(stderr, "unknown line");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for the help, I will continue to adjust my code accordingly and return with the results.